# Why must I explicitly inherit object for slots to work as advertised?

Tags: python

A colleague of mine recently showed me the following session:

```
>>> class Foo:
...     __slots__ = ['x']
...     def __init__(self):
...             self.x = "x"
... 
>>> f = Foo()
>>> f.x
'x'
>>> f.y = 1
>>> class Bar(object):
...     __slots__ = ['x']
...     def __init__(self):
...             self.x = "x"
... 
>>> b = Bar()
>>> b.x
'x'
>>> b.y = 1
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'Bar' object has no attribute 'y'
```

According to the [Python documentation](http://docs.python.org/release/2.5.2/ref/slots.html), defining `__slots__` should make it impossible to assign any other variables than the ones specified in slots, unless the user provides a dict instance manually:

The documentation says nothing about an explicit need to inherit from `object` like `Bar` does.

Why does this happen?

Comment: *The default can be overridden by defining __slots__ in a new-style class definition.* The manual says.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It does say it, just not very explicitly:

> The default can be overridden by defining __slots__ in a new-style class definition.

In Python 2, when you inherit from `object`, you're creating a new-style class. If you don't, it's an old-style class.

Comment: Ah, thanks for pointing that out. It looks like I have some reading up to do.

Comment: There's little need to understand old-style classes, and they're gone in Python 3 anyway. For an interesting read, though, see [Guido's blog post on new-style classes](http://python-history.blogspot.com/2010/06/new-style-classes.html).

Answer (score 0):

As Jamie pointed out, you want a new-style class. here's why:

```
In [5]: import sys

In [6]: sys.getsizeof(f)
Out[6]: 36

In [7]: sys.getsizeof(b)
Out[7]: 28

In [8]: sys.getsizeof(f.__dict__)
Out[8]: 140

In [9]: sys.getsizeof(b.__dict__)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-9-891152de459e> in <module>()
----> 1 sys.getsizeof(b.__dict__)

AttributeError: 'Bar' object has no attribute '__dict__'
```

In other words, your `Foo` class doesn't actually use slots, it still uses `__dict__` to store member variables, thus total size of `f` is 176 bytes and `b` 28 bytes (figures for 32-bit arch). It is also why you can assign `f.y = 1`.

Presumably you want `__slots__` to reduce memory usage or to force users of your objects to touch only slotted variables. `Bar` does both. `Foo` does neither.